# Arithmetic problem with logarithm

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

This is the question which I am referring to

> if log(base 3 of 2), log (base 3 of (2^(x)-5)), log(base 3 of (2^(x)-(7/2))
>   are in AP, find the value of x

My try and answer

I used the equation 2b= a+c , where a, b, c are in AP and solved for x so I got the answer
log (base 2 of (6+(2)^(1/2)) and log (base 2 of (6-(2)^(1/2)) which comes out to be 2.89 and 2.17 respectively
Is my way to solve question correct?
Correct answer is 3.

Comment: Your use of parentheses is pretty confusing. First, in the last term, is it 2^x - (7/2)  or (2^x-7)/2 ?? Also, you coul visit here to properly write mathematics in this site:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference

Comment: I have edited now.

Comment: No, you didn't in fact. At least, not what I remarked above!

Comment: **Now** you did...good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read, understand and justify the following (assuming we have $\;2^x-\frac72\;$ in the last term):

$$\log_32\;,\;\;\log_3(2^x-5)=\log_32+d\;,\;\;\log_3\left(2^x-\frac72\right)=\log_32+2d$$

and also  (we drop the subindex $\;3\;$ )

$$2\log(2^x-5)=\log2+\log\left(2^x-\frac72\right)=\log(2^{x+1}-7)\implies$$

$$2^{2x}-10\cdot2^x+25=2\cdot2^x-7$$

Substitute accordingly and get the quadratic $\;t^2-12t+32=(t-8)(t-4)\;$ , and end the exercise.

Comment: I did it till that second last part and did blunder by using 18 instead of 32.

Comment: @KartikWatwani Yes, sometimes our mistakes are littly, silly things...but which can affect greatly. Good it was only that.